# Building Grails Web App With ASP.NET RESTFul Backend

Tags: .net, rest, grails

We are developing the backend of a trading exchange and exposing it through the ASP.NET RESTFul API. We also plan to provide a web front end for users that prefer to trade using the website. However, the only team we have available for building the front end has expertise in Grails, so we have planned to build the front end using Grails with AngularJS.

What would be the best way(s) to host the two applications and is there any downside to using different stacks i.e. .NET for backend and Java for front end? I'm specifically looking for concerns related to performance, security (and any other) as a result of the hosting options.

Comment: Why don't you implement a AngularJS App using your .NET REST API directly?

Comment: We can go with AngularJS. However I'm not sure how to implement security if we go this route.

Comment: How would you implement security if the grails server uses the .NET REST API? At the moment I did not see the need for grails and a .NET backend ...

Comment: I work on a Grails app that does this - backend is written in Spring MVC and exposes web services that are consumed by the Grails app. The security model we use, is the Grails app and Spring MVC app talk to each other behind the DMZ and pass an api-key (for write changes) and thus the backend app trusts the credential the Grails app send to it, as coming from the logged in user (if that makes sense).

Comment: thanks, we'll explore this further.

Comment: @aiolos there was no specific need. It is due to the availability of teams in those specific technologies, so we're trying to make up our mind

Comment: @aiolos expanding my earlier question..How would we secure API keys in a JavaScript app if we choose to use AngularJS only?

Comment: Depends on your .NET implementation. I have no experiences using .NET - sorry. If you stick with grails - the [Spring Security REST Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest) looks promising ...